# I am getting data from an API in form of <class 'str'> i wanted to extract all the fields using python language

Tags: python, json

this is sample data that i am getting . i wanted to extract all the 
field .the actual data is in nested form so i need to extract all the information. i wanted to extracted this data in python .
This is what i have tried so far .

```
d=json.loads(studentInformation) 
print(type(d))
j=d['data']
for data in j:
 for items in j:
        print(items)
        print(type(items))

 I wanted to get email,student name, last name,DOB and other 
 information too for inserting data into database



{"data":[{"data":{"email":"emma.jinglehimer 
schmidt.342153@example.com","grade":"5","graduation_year":"","name": 
{"middle":"Sageglaze","first":"Emma","last":"Jinglehimer 
schmidt"},"created":"2018-06- 
26T06:43:23.263Z","school":"5b31dfc6f1b3e71dee60c9e4","credentials": 
{"district_username":""},"hispanic_ethnicity":"","location": 
{"address":"","city":"","lat":"","lon":"","state":"","zip":""},
"district":"5b31de310fcdac00017e46fe","race":"","gender":"M",
"last_modified":"2018-06- 
26T06:43:23.263Z","sis_id":"342153","state_id":"1049413026","schools": 
["5b31dfc6f1b3e71dee60c9e4"],
"student_number":"342153","dob":"7/14/2004",
"id":"5b31dfccf1b3e71dee6185d6"},
"uri":"/v2.0/students/5b31dfccf1b3e71dee6185d6"},{"data": 
{"credentials":{"district_username":""},"race":"","location": 
{"lon":"","state":"","zip":"","address":"","city":"","lat":""},
"gender":"F","student_number":"342392","created":"2018-06- 
26T06:43:23.265Z",
"district":"5b31de310fcdac00017e46fe","dob":"8/11/2008",
"graduation_year":"","school":"5b31dfc6f1b3e71dee60c9e4",
"state_id":"1011436920","hispanic_ethnicity":"",
"email":"kistiñe.garcia.342392@example.com","last_modified":"2018-06- 
26T06:43:23.265Z","name": 
{"first":"Kistiñe","last":"Garcia","middle":"Robinbush"},
"schools":["5b31dfc6f1b3e71dee60c9e4"],"grade":"2","sis_id":"342392",
"id":"5b31dfccf1b3e71dee6185d7"},
"uri":"/v2.0/students/5b31dfccf1b3e71dee6185d7"}]}
```

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code?

Comment: extract what exactly out of it??? its just a simple dictionary throw keys  get values

Comment: So what's your question? This is obviously JSON, what's preventing you from using it?

Comment: This is what i have tried so far . 
I wanted to get field like student first name, last, DOB and other fields too
d=json.loads(studentInformation)
print(type(d))
j=d['data']
for data in j:
 for items in j:
  print(items)
  print(type(items))

Comment: @DanielRoseman I wanted to get fields like first name, last name, DOB etc.

Comment: @RahulRajpoot and where's the problem? You just work with the data like any other python dictionary...

Comment: @AndrejKesely this is a nested data . so i do not know exactly way to get one field 
when i tried 
print(schoolInformation['email'])
then i got this type error : string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `namedtuple` for storing your variables in your program, that way it becomes clearer. (Assuming your json parsed data is in the `j` variable):

```
from collections import namedtuple
from pprint import pprint

StudendInfo = namedtuple('StudendInfo', 'name last_name email dob')

# ...populate your j variable from Json here

info = []
for v in j['data']:
    i = StudendInfo(name=v['data']['name']['first'],
                    last_name=v['data']['name']['last'],
                    email=v['data']['email'],
                    dob=v['data']['dob'])
    info.append(i)

pprint(info)
```

Will print:

```
[StudendInfo(name='Emma', last_name='Jinglehimerschmidt', email='emma.jinglehimerschmidt.342153@example.com', dob='7/14/2004'),
 StudendInfo(name='Kistiñe', last_name='Garcia', email='kistiñe.garcia.342392@example.com', dob='8/11/2008')]
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej Kesely : i have got the solution ,  i did this
info=json.loads(studentInformation)
print(info['data'])

for v in info['data']:
 email=v['data']['email']
 print(email)